# Selenium WebDriver selection and entering text

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I recently was able to get a headless webdriver up and going and have been tinkering with some. Currently, I'm having trouble locating an element by its xpath and changing its text. Below, I am trying to return the "ENTER TEXT HERE" to the console, then change the text to something like "hello world" and then display the newly changed element text.

HTML:

```
<div id="textfield" class="newInput">
    <div>ENTER TEXT HERE</div>
</div>
```

Upon selecting the xpath I get this:

```
//*[@id='textfield']/div
```

This is all fine and good but I'm confused as how to go about changing the text.
Trying to store "ENTER TEXT HERE" in a variable I tried:

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

defaultText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").getText()
print defaultText
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").textContent = "hello world"
defaultText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").getText()
print defaultText


#Attempt to store "ENTER TEXT HERE" into variable
#Attempt to print ENTER TEXT HERE in console
#Change text to "hello world"
#Update string in variable
#Attempt to print hello world in console
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks to Richard for pointing out the send_keys(),
I'm now in a predicament where if there is no text by default and you try to send a string, it throws an exception. The trace leads to .check_response in the webdriver error handler.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 116, in <module>
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").send_keys("hello world")
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 293, in send_keys
          self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
          return self._parent.execute(command, params)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
          self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
          raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'{"errorMessage":"\'undefined\'             
is not an object (evaluating \'b.value.length\')","request":{"headers":   
{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-    
Length":"147","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF8","Host":"127.0.0.1:XXXXX",
"User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.6"},"httpVersion":"1.1","
method":"POST","post":"{\\"sessionId\\": \\"561558d0-36a9-11e4-c9e7-c90efed32dfc\\",     
\\"id\\": \\":wdc:1410101175394\\", \\"value\
\": [\\"h\\", \\"e\\", \\"l\\", \\"l\\", \\"o\\", \\" \\", \\"w\\", \\"o\\", \\"r\\",     
\\"l\\", \\"d\\"]}","url":"/value","urlParsed":
{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"value","directory":"/","path":"/value","relative":"/value",
"port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"",
"source":"/value","queryKey":{},"chunks":["value"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/561
558d0-36a9-11e4-c9e7-c90efed32dfc/element/%3Awdc%3A1410101175394/value"}}' ; 
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the text to a value, you need to use `send_keys()` to set the text of an element.  Additionally, `getText()` is the java method of getting text from an element, you need to use `text` with python.

```
defaultText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").text
print defaultText
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").send_keys("hello world")
defaultText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='textfield']/div").text
print defaultText
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see thank you! I am also error checking and if I pass an empty string or if the field is empty by default, it throws an error ('\undefined\' is not an object). This has to do with the send_keys(),  correct? Do you know if there is a workaround? Thank you for your help